# Azure SignalR ServiceManagerBuilder Singleton, Transient or Scoped?

Tags: azure-signalr

We are using the Azure SignalR service from functions to send messages back to our UI and all is working without issue.  But I can't find a definitive answer on how long lived the ServiceManager or HubContext should be.

At the moment each time we want to send a message to the UI we call a class we have written which does the following:

```
using var serviceManager = return new ServiceManagerBuilder().WithOptions(option =>
                {
                    option.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
                    option.ServiceTransportType = ServiceTransportType.Persistent;
                })
                .WithNewtonsoftJson()
                .BuildServiceManager();


await using var hubContext = await serviceManager .CreateHubContextAsync(hubName, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

await hubContext.Clients.Group(group).SendAsync(method, message);
```

This all works fine, but we are creating a new ServiceManager and ServiceHubContext every time we send a message.

The samples I have looked at do not include running in functions where we inject a service which handles publishing.  Should either of these be Singleton?  The functions we have are processing data and sending updates in a loop so we may send 100s of messages in a single function.

Comment: Have the same question. I'm also trying to understand whether creation of new HubContext instance will result in creation of the new connection between client (Azure Function) and SignalR service

Comment: I asked on the repo and they responded: https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1578, HubContext is safe to be singleton.